# Conditional formatting is not working for dates comparison

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting, conditional-statements

Trying to implement conditional formatting (row colouring) for two columns - one string and one date condition (I do this in two approaches, but none of them works):

```
> Dim y As Date
>     y = DateAdd("d", 30, Date) Debug.Print y Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
>      "=OR(AND($H2=""1. Qualify"",$P2=""Google"", Days(now(),$Z2)<30  ),AND($H2=""1. Qualify"",$P2=""AWS"", $Z2 <
> DateValue(y)))"
>          Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
>     With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
>         .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
>         .Color = vbRed
>         .TintAndShade = 0
>     End With
>     Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Any idea of the reason why?

Comment: `y` falls inside the quotes in that formula, so it is not a variable, but just the text "y".

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful information. I will continue digging into it by excepting this option. What about the first one - "Days(now(),$Z2)<30"? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my question is to use the NOW() function:

```
$Z2<NOW()+30
```